# Graphic tablet DEXP Leggero-M(GT-M101) does not work properly on Linux Manjaro

Tags: linux, driver, manjaro

I`ve recently bought a graphic tablet DEXP Leggero-M(GT-M101). On windows it works good, but on my Manjaro linux it works like if it was plugged to android: only half of the workspace are used, and because of it the oX sensivity is much higher, then oY and no settings or bindings options can be reached.

I tried to search for drivers, but found nothing. When I use lsusb I can see this:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:5480 IMC Networks HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. Bluetooth 9460/9560 Jefferson Peak (JfP)
**Bus 001 Device 008: ID 08f2:6811 Gotop Information Inc. [T501] Driver Inside Tablet**
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
```

I tried to use 10moons-tools, but it give no effect: just no output, 10moons-tools neither says "wrong arguments", nor give any other instructions.

It there any way to set-up this tablet? Tablet has drivers for windows, maybe I can somehow use them on linux?